# DataFrame is a string dtype and calculating diff with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to get the difference between two rows for a specific column and did this.

```
df['Dif'] = df['assists'].diff()
```

df

I got this error:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-c75745166e41> in <module>
----> 1 df['Dif'] = df['assists'].diff()
      2 df

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

So I checked the type of my DataFrame and found it is a string.

Is this why I can't do the calculation?

I am somewhat uncertain as I could do other calculations like take the mean, std, etc.

And if this is the problem..how can I convert it to int or float?

Also, I have ints and floats in my data.

DataFrame:

[image]

Comment: This looks like an issue with your index type not your dtype. You should post an example of your data though and it would make it easier to help.

Comment: @brobertsp I have added the df in question.

Comment: What is the full traceback, because that error seems to be very odd for this manipulation.

Comment: Yes this error makes sense because it looks like team is your index which is a string column. If you look at the examples in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) you need an integer index column because that is how diff decides which rows to compare. I would just make a new index that has sequential integers and it should work.

Comment: @brobertsp So you can't have a string index?

Comment: You can definitely have a string index in general, you just can't use a string index with this particular operation.

Comment: @brobertsp How do I keep track of what the row/record represents?

Comment: You can still have team as a column so you will know what category that row represents, just don't have it as the index.

Comment: @brobertsp Having some issues changing the index or dropping it and assigning the index column as a regular column.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#create some fake data to work with-  index set to 'Team' to mimic your df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team':['Bruins','Maple Leafs','Redwings'],'goals':[145,167,234],'penalty_minutes':[45,6,124], 'assists':[453,452,675]}).set_index('Team')

#reset the index- this does two things 1) it removes Team as index and 2) it defaults to a numeric index
df = df.reset_index()

#do your differencing 
df['dif'] = df['assists'].diff()
```

Comment: @ed84 if you could accept that answer if it solved your issue that would be terrific.